# How to open a new tab in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to make extension that opens bookmark link in new tab when user is in pinned tab (tab is in focus)?

Comment: Can't you just middle click on your bookmark?

Comment: Laptop doesn't have middle click, which is the reason I need this extension.

Comment: You can't register a click event on bookmark links.

Comment: Control click also works

Answer (score 1):

this method will allow you to open all of your bookmarks in a new tab directly .
all you have to do is to replace your bookmark's url to this code :

```
javascript:(function(){ 
   var str = this.location.toString();
   var url = 'http://INSERT_BOOKMARK_URL_HERE' ; 
   if ( !str.includes('/_/chrome/newtab') ) window.open(url); 
   else this.location.replace(url);
})();
```

replacing "**INSERT_BOOKMARK_URL_HERE**" with the desired url , giving attention that it must start with "**http://**" ,
exemple: my bookmark is google home page "google.com", the bookmark should be like this :

```
javascript:(function(){ 
   var str = this.location.toString();
   var url = 'http://google.com' ; 
   if ( !str.includes('/_/chrome/newtab') ) window.open(url); 
   else this.location.replace(url);
})();
```

**NOTE** : this code is made by me and its designed to work with the chrome's native new tab 
so when your current open tab is the default new tab the code will open the page within the current tab
so if you are using a custom tab just replace its url with  "  **/_/chrome/newtab** " in the code , 
or if you don't like this idea at  all  just use this code the same as the previous one except it will always 
open bookmark in new tab

```
 javascript:window.open('http://INSERT_BOOKMARK_URL_HERE');
```

that's it hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

New Tab Redirect!  a extension that Sets a user-specified URL to load in new tabs.

Comment: Well, that only changed new tab. It is not opening bookmark link in the new tab when user is in pinned tab.

Comment: I know what you mean, but whether open link in the new tag page display is a web page code decision